# Python: pickling locals(), or does locals have a lighterweight cousin?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm working in Django.  In Django, when you're rendering a template you send it a context dictionary to get replaced.  Because I'm lazy/DRY, i often use locals() as a shortcut instead of sending a dictionary that looks like {'my_var': my_var, 'var2': var2}.

This usually works beautifully, and saves a lot of mind-numbing repetition.

I'm using django-notifications to send emails when certain events happen - say you receive a private message.  Django-notifications comes with a built-in queuing feature that I am integrating now.

However, the problem is that django-notifications pickles the context dictionary at queue time.  This is where the locals() trick fails -- the dictionary from locals has a LOT of crap in it beyond the local variables (e.g. it has **import** and int()).  The dictionary created by locals doesn't pickle.

I see three options: 1) rewrite the queueing method of django-notifications to render the template before it is stored (straightforward but a bit tedious and breaks upgradability) 2) stop using the locals trick and start repeating myself 3) Try to find a lighter-weight version of locals (or a way to pickle locals).

I'm here hoping someone has leads in the direction of #3.

In case it might be relevant, here is the error I get when I try to pickle using the locals() shortcut:

```
TypeError: can't pickle ellipsis objects
```

Further, the dictionary output of locals():

```
{
    '__builtins__': 
    {
        'bytearray': <type 'bytearray'>,
         'IndexError': <type 'exceptions.IndexError'>,
         'all': <built-in function all>,
         'help': Type help() for interactive help,
         or help(object) for help about object.,
         'vars': <built-in function vars>,
         'SyntaxError': <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>,
         'unicode': <type 'unicode'>,
         'UnicodeDecodeError': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>,
         'isinstance': <built-in function isinstance>,
         'copyright': Copyright (c) 2001-2010 Python Software Foundation.
All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 2000 BeOpen.com.
All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 1995-2001 Corporation for National Research Initiatives.
All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 1991-1995 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum,
         Amsterdam.
All Rights Reserved.,
         'NameError': <type 'exceptions.NameError'>,
         'BytesWarning': <type 'exceptions.BytesWarning'>,
         'dict': <type 'dict'>,
         'input': <built-in function input>,
         'oct': <built-in function oct>,
         'bin': <built-in function bin>,
         'SystemExit': <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>,
         'StandardError': <type 'exceptions.StandardError'>,
         'format': <built-in function format>,
         'repr': <built-in function repr>,
         'sorted': <built-in function sorted>,
         'False': False,
         'RuntimeWarning': <type 'exceptions.RuntimeWarning'>,
         'list': <type 'list'>,
         'iter': <built-in function iter>,
         'reload': <built-in function reload>,
         'Warning': <type 'exceptions.Warning'>,
         '__package__': None,
         'round': <built-in function round>,
         'dir': <built-in function dir>,
         'cmp': <built-in function cmp>,
         'set': <type 'set'>,
         'bytes': <type 'str'>,
         'reduce': <built-in function reduce>,
         'intern': <built-in function intern>,
         'issubclass': <built-in function issubclass>,
         'Ellipsis': Ellipsis,
         'EOFError': <type 'exceptions.EOFError'>,
         'locals': <built-in function locals>,
         'BufferError': <type 'exceptions.BufferError'>,
         'slice': <type 'slice'>,
         'FloatingPointError': <type 'exceptions.FloatingPointError'>,
         'sum': <built-in function sum>,
         'getattr': <built-in function getattr>,
         'abs': <built-in function abs>,
         'exit': Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit,
         'print': <built-in function print>,
         'True': True,
         'FutureWarning': <type 'exceptions.FutureWarning'>,
         'ImportWarning': <type 'exceptions.ImportWarning'>,
         'None': None,
         'hash': <built-in function hash>,
         'ReferenceError': <type 'exceptions.ReferenceError'>,
         'len': <built-in function len>,
         'credits':     Thanks to CWI,
         CNRI,
         BeOpen.com,
         Zope Corporation and a cast of thousands
    for supporting Python development.  See www.python.org for more information.,
         'frozenset': <type 'frozenset'>,
         '__name__': '__builtin__',
         'ord': <built-in function ord>,
         'super': <type 'super'>,
         '_': None,
         'TypeError': <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>,
         'license': Type license() to see the full license text,
         'KeyboardInterrupt': <type 'exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt'>,
         'UserWarning': <type 'exceptions.UserWarning'>,
         'filter': <built-in function filter>,
         'range': <built-in function range>,
         'staticmethod': <type 'staticmethod'>,
         'SystemError': <type 'exceptions.SystemError'>,
         'BaseException': <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>,
         'pow': <built-in function pow>,
         'RuntimeError': <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>,
         'float': <type 'float'>,
         'MemoryError': <type 'exceptions.MemoryError'>,
         'StopIteration': <type 'exceptions.StopIteration'>,
         'globals': <built-in function globals>,
         'divmod': <built-in function divmod>,
         'enumerate': <type 'enumerate'>,
         'apply': <built-in function apply>,
         'LookupError': <type 'exceptions.LookupError'>,
         'open': <built-in function open>,
         'quit': Use quit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit,
         'basestring': <type 'basestring'>,
         'UnicodeError': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeError'>,
         'zip': <built-in function zip>,
         'hex': <built-in function hex>,
         'long': <type 'long'>,
         'next': <built-in function next>,
         'ImportError': <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>,
         'chr': <built-in function chr>,
         'xrange': <type 'xrange'>,
         'type': <type 'type'>,
         '__doc__': "Built-in functions,
         exceptions,
         and other objects.\n\nNoteworthy: None is the `nil' object; Ellipsis represents `...' in slices.",
         'Exception': <type 'exceptions.Exception'>,
         'tuple': <type 'tuple'>,
         'UnicodeTranslateError': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeTranslateError'>,
         'reversed': <type 'reversed'>,
         'UnicodeEncodeError': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>,
         'IOError': <type 'exceptions.IOError'>,
         'hasattr': <built-in function hasattr>,
         'delattr': <built-in function delattr>,
         'setattr': <built-in function setattr>,
         'raw_input': <built-in function raw_input>,
         'SyntaxWarning': <type 'exceptions.SyntaxWarning'>,
         'compile': <built-in function compile>,
         'ArithmeticError': <type 'exceptions.ArithmeticError'>,
         'str': <type 'str'>,
         'property': <type 'property'>,
         'GeneratorExit': <type 'exceptions.GeneratorExit'>,
         'int': <type 'int'>,
         '__import__': <built-in function __import__>,
         'KeyError': <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>,
         'coerce': <built-in function coerce>,
         'PendingDeprecationWarning': <type 'exceptions.PendingDeprecationWarning'>,
         'file': <type 'file'>,
         'EnvironmentError': <type 'exceptions.EnvironmentError'>,
         'unichr': <built-in function unichr>,
         'id': <built-in function id>,
         'OSError': <type 'exceptions.OSError'>,
         'DeprecationWarning': <type 'exceptions.DeprecationWarning'>,
         'min': <built-in function min>,
         'UnicodeWarning': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeWarning'>,
         'execfile': <built-in function execfile>,
         'any': <built-in function any>,
         'complex': <type 'complex'>,
         'bool': <type 'bool'>,
         'ValueError': <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>,
         'NotImplemented': NotImplemented,
         'map': <built-in function map>,
         'buffer': <type 'buffer'>,
         'max': <built-in function max>,
         'object': <type 'object'>,
         'TabError': <type 'exceptions.TabError'>,
         'callable': <built-in function callable>,
         'ZeroDivisionError': <type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>,
         'eval': <built-in function eval>,
         '__debug__': True,
         'IndentationError': <type 'exceptions.IndentationError'>,
         'AssertionError': <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>,
         'classmethod': <type 'classmethod'>,
         'UnboundLocalError': <type 'exceptions.UnboundLocalError'>,
         'NotImplementedError': <type 'exceptions.NotImplementedError'>,
         'AttributeError': <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>,
         'OverflowError': <type 'exceptions.OverflowError'>
    },
     'notification': <module 'notification.models' from '/home/b/webapps/myapp/notification/models.pyc'>,
     'u': <User: abcd>,
     'User': <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
}
```

Comment: I think your problem started with being just a bit too clever. Just because you *can* do something (e.g. use `locals()` as a dict for Context) doesn't mean that it's a good idea. Building the dict directly, with the values you want in it explicitly stated, does not take a whole lot of time and it completely avoids this other 'created' problem. Study the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and note item 2.

Comment: when you have 15 objects, the time savings of locals() is appreciable.  The god-this-repetition-sucks weighted savings even moreso.

Comment: Yeah, but look at how much time you're having to waste on SO. In all of the Django sites I've done, I rarely have had a view-specific context that has more than 6 values. On the other hand, I do have a general [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) that supplies all sorts of generally useful info for our templates.

Comment: It may be that notifications, because it has intermediate steps before rendering, is an exception to the usefulness of locals(). render_to_response doesn't work with notifications either.  But, not working with notifications doesn't mean that either shortcut is a waste of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Its worth repeating yourself if you are going to pickle.  Lots of objects, some of them unintuitive, are unable to be pickled (i.e. form input).

The locals() shortcut should only be used when you are certain that the template will be rendered immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Please allow me to propose an alternative to using `locals()`

```
class Object(object):
    pass

def foo():
    result = Object()
    result.my_var = 'bar'
    your_var = 'not to be returned'
    result.var2 = 'baz' + result.my_var + len(your_var)
    return result.__dict__
```

Another option would be to just add objects to the context as you create them.

```
def foo():
    result = {}
    result['my_var'] = my_var = 'bar'
    your_var = 'not to be returned'
    result['var2'] = var2 = 'baz' + my_var + len(your_var)
    return result
```

Although, make sure that the multiple assignment occurs every time you modify the variable (or at least the very last time).

**edit:** *You should be using that second version.*  I'm sure the additional keystrokes of using the context dict (`result` or `ctx` or whatever) doesn't feel very DRY, but let me tell you that this is actually a good thing.  The Zen of Python states *"Explicit is better than implicit."*  When you return the value of `locals()`, you are returning who knows what.  Everything that was in the global namespace, everything that's in a nested namespace, every intermediate calculation you may have made, all of those things are implicitly returned to the caller.

If you create a container for the value you wish to return, you are making explicit your intent, drawing a sharp line between

```
this_is_for_me = 'foo'
```

and

```
result['this_is_for_you'] = 'bar'
```

The difference is clear in the code what is public, for use by others; and private, subject to change, implementation specific.  It's also clear to the caller, because those private values are simply unavailable.

And if you are integrating an external library that never-the-less uses `locals()` magic, you should be very hesitant about where and how you use it.  I would probably prefer to *patch* the code that does this over any other option available.

Comment: Or even simpler, write to the context dict directly (i.e. wherever you'd use local `a`, use `ctx['a']` instead).

Comment: I had origininally planned on using a plain dict, but I think that the poster might object to having to type the three extra characters, `result['my_var']` instead of `result.my_var`.  Yes, I really prefer to just use a regular dict.

Comment: This is a good solution, but in the context of django where object.variable isn't a community standard its doesn't really work.  It would mean that if I pull in a community app I have to go through and redo all of their functions to store local variables in a local object -- which to me makes this a non starter.

Comment: why would you have to change an external app?  does the app not return the right data?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything in your code snippet from `locals()` that is 'un-pickleable' with [dill](http://pythonhosted.org/dill).
Dill can serialize almost anything in python, and also has [some good tools](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/detect.py) for helping you understand what is causing your pickling to fail when your code fails.  As long as `django` uses `pickle` and not `cPickle`, all you have to do to extend pickle to serialize things like the `EllipsisType` is:

```
>>> import dill
>>> # this will enable python's pickle to pickle almost everything dill can pickle
>>> 
>>> # on the full set of dill's types, this usually works unless there's a generator
>>> # or an interator-type or something odd like a traceback object in locals
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(locals()))
>>> ...
>>> # if you get a pickling error, use dill's tools to figure out a workaround
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(your_bad_object, depth=0)
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(your_bad_object, depth=1)
>>> ...
```

If you absolutely wanted to, you could use dill's `badobjects` (or one of the other detection functions) to dive recursively into everything in the `locals()` reference chain, and pop out the unpickleable objects, instead of calling it at at every depth, as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably store the everything in locals that is not in globals.